How can I finish a joint between drywall and tile near a corner when the drywall is 1/2" proud of the tile?
I am renovating a portion of a basement bathroom to undo some shoddy work by a previous owner.  The bathroom has an existing glass enclosed tiled shower in the rear corner of the room.  I had to deconstruct the wall down to the cinder block on one side of the room right up to the point where it meets the shower tile (a few inches outside the glass shower wall).
There is a capped 3" plumbing stub coming out of the slab where it meets the cinder block on this wall.  I am planning on building the new wall 1" off the cinder block to allow for 1" foamboard which will also ensure that the stub is enclosed in the wall.
The problem is that this puts the studs more or less flush with the finished tile and the drywall will sit proud by its full thickness.
What are my options to finish this and have it look good?
Here are some pictures for clarification
Closeup
Right side showing tiled area
Left side showing 3" pipe

need a picture...

I don't understand. I assume the tile is on the cinder block. No? If you're adding 1 inch of foam, a stud and drywall, there will be a 5-in rebate next to the glass. The question says half an inch.

Can't you simply use narrower framing—basically furring strips?  It looks like there's plenty of space between the drywall and the pipe in your "Closeup" pic.

The pipe in the closeup is 1-1/2".  The pipe in the left side picture is 3" and that's what is dictating the overall framing width.

You can rip 1/2 inch off all the studs.
Then add a firring strip to the existing stud at the end of the tile and attach your drywall to make everything on the same plane.
Or you can use a Vinyl J-Bead on the edge of the drywall to make it finished. Then caulk the corner where it meets the tile.

The J-Bead was the way to go.  I taped and mudded the front edge so you can't even tell it's there. Here is the finished wall:https://i.sstatic.net/yruOXxc0.jpg

I agree with @RMDman's answer: rip the new studs down to fit.
To finish the drywall end at the tile, I suggest using a tear-away L bead to provide a clean transition. This will also make mudding much easier. After mudding and painting, apply a bead of caulking along the joint between the L bead and the tile.

If you do not have access to a table saw, you can create a ripping jig with some 2x4s, sawhorses, and a circular saw:


Ripping studs will not work because of the 3" pipe on the left side.  When I say 3" pipe, this is the NPS pipe size.  The true diameter is 3.5" and with the addition of the pipe cap and the small gap between the cinder block and the pipe it is approaching 4" for the studs to clear the pipe.  I've purchased a piece of J-bead (thanks to @RMDman for giving me the name of something for which to search) to mock it up.  If it looks good, I'll mark their post as correct.

If the outside edge of the cap sits at 4" off the cinderblock, it will protrude out past the drywall by a 1/2". You could conceal it by using a baseboard that is thicker than 1/2" and notch out the backside at the cap location.
